# How do I produce a non-distinct union of strings with LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, string, linq, ienumerable, union

Given the following two `IEnumerable(Of String)` of unknown length, how can I produce the non-distinct union?

```
Dim theseStrings As IEnumerable(Of String) =
    {"true", "true", "true", "true", "true"}
Dim thoseStrings As Ienumerable(Of String) =
    {"false", "true", "false", "false"}
```

The result should look like:

```
{"false", "true", "false", "false", "true"}
```

Which means

- The `Count` of the `result` **must equal** the `Count` of `theseStrings`
- Where the two disagree, `thoseStrings` takes priority

Rules

- No lists or anything concrete
- No loops

I've tried

```
Dim result = theseStrings.Union(thoseStrings)
' result = {"true"}

Dim result = theseString.Concat(thoseStrings)
' result = {"true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "false", "true", "false", "false"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of String) =
    theseStrings.Select(
        Function(value, index) _
            If(thoseStrings(index) IsNot Nothing, thoseString(index), value))
```

Please comment if this can be cleaned up.